# Mod rewrite redirect every subdirectory to the same file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website with a `products.html` file. Now, inside this file, I will have some Javascript code that checks the url to show the correct products/categories. This are some examples of the urls:

```
example.com/products
example.com/products/
example.com/products/shoes
example.com/products/shoes/
example.com/products/shoes/adidas
example.com/products/shoes/adidas/
example.com/products/shoes/adidas/adidas-predator-20.3
example.com/products/shoes/adidas/adidas-predator-20.3/
```

So basically, I want that everytime someone goes to the any of the above urls, I want to get the file `products.html`, I'll manage the rest with JS.

Also I want to be able to test this on my local machine. In this case, my URLs will be:

```
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/shoes
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/shoes/
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/shoes/adidas
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/shoes/adidas/
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/shoes/adidas/adidas-predator-20.3
localhost/websites/myWebsite/products/shoes/adidas/adidas-predator-20.3/
```

So I think we would need two htaccess files right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this single rule that will work on localhost and on production host as well:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (?:^|/)products(?:/|$) products.html [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples could you please try following, you should place .htaccess file on same level where folder products is present. Also place the products.html in same level too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:products)/?((?:shoes)/?((?:adidas)/?((?:adidas-predator-20\.3)/?)?)?)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ products.html [L]
```

If these are the only rules you will have then change `L` to `END` as an additional note here.